# submit by enter won't function using ng-submit in Chrome (but works in Firefox)

Tags: html, forms, angularjs, submit

I did a seemingly correct layout of form, but submit does not happen whet I hit enter after entering password. I need to click the button to do submit. I base my approach on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit with only exception that I use button, not input.

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" ng-submit="login(credentials)"       novalidate="novalidate">
   <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="credentials.password" ng-maxlength="40" required="required" form-control="form-control" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required">
   <button type="submit" id="loginButton" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button> 
 </form>
```

**UPDATE** The behaviour works in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: writing alert in side ng-submit will not work. you need to call method from controller which will be binded to view using $scope.

Comment: login is such a method but it is not called :(

Answer (score 0):

`ng-submit` does not accept JavaScript, it accepts an [angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

As such, your code there won't work.

**IF** `login` is a function on the scope accessible by this markup, then the following will work:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login(credentials)" novalidate>
```

If this isn't working, then check your developer console - are there any errors? It's very likely your function isn't on the scope that you think it's on. Provide your javascript in the question for a more accurate answer.

Comment and I will update if you still need help.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I found out that form works as intended but only in Firefox. in Chrome it does not. No console errors. Any clues :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. check the element that contains your form. my form overflowed outside of it's containing DOM element and submit button was accidentally in the overflowed section (the height of the containing div was less than the height of the form). As I positioned it inside, it worked.
I still don't know what causes this problem in Chrome. maybe it is angular's behavior in Chrome.

**EDIT :**

you can also try fixing it by removing any given height from form's parent element.